# Storybook integration with Expo React Native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

I am trying to get Storybook running on a react native app build by Expo. I generated my project with:

```
expo init storybook-test
```

I entered the folder and ran:

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react_native
```

...which I got from [this tutorial](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/) and it added multiple files and folders such as:

```
- Root
- - storybook
- - - stories
- - - addons.js
- - - index.js
- - - rn-addons.js
```

It then told me to:

> add the following to your entrypoint (usually App.js or index.js).

```
export {default} from "./storybook";
```

**I wasn't sure what that means** as `storybook>index.js` already has a default export:

```
export default StorybookUIRoot;
```

I then edited my `root/storybook/index.js` as there is no `main.js` in my project to the following:

```
// if you use expo remove this line
// import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import { getStorybookUI, configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react-native';
// import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

import './rn-addons';

// enables knobs for all stories
// addDecorator(withKnobs);

// import stories
configure(() => {
  require('./stories');
}, module);

// Refer to https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/tree/master/app/react-native#getstorybookui-options
// To find allowed options for getStorybookUI
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({});

// If you are using React Native vanilla and after installation you don't see your app name here, write it manually.
// If you use Expo you should remove this line.
// AppRegistry.registerComponent('%APP_NAME%', () => StorybookUIRoot);

export default StorybookUIRoot;
```

After all this, I ran `yarn storybook` and it opened the webpage but the stories never load.

What am I doing wrong?!